# How to aggregate multiple NC files into gridded data

Tags: python, google-earth-engine, atmospheric-correction, bash, esa

I would like to convert daily total NO2 column data into an aggregate form [similar to the monthly mean tropospheric NO2 columns](http://www.temis.nl/airpollution/no2.html) on said website in order to later extract statistics using shapefile(s), but am currently unsure of how to best do this. Currently I'm trying to [use harp to grid the data into L3 form](http://stcorp.github.io/harp/doc/html/python.html), but my output doesn't look correct. [Google Earth Engine](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/COPERNICUS_S5P_NRTI_L3_NO2) provides a good example of functionality that I would like to achieve, except I want years earlier than 2018 (which is why I'm using the Temis NO2 dataset). For example, when running

harpmerge -a 'latitude>-90;latitude<90;longitude>-180;longitude<180' -ap 'bin_spatial(1801,-90,0.1,1801,-90,0.1)' QA4ECV* l3.nc

I get the strange image [image: Bad Image]

Whereas a correct image would look like this:

[image: Good Image]

And now I'm really stuck. Any tips and/or tricks, including libraries which aren't too hard to use?

Comment: This is a question about using the harp binary, so it's probably not suitable for the google-earth-engine category